# I need some clarification with the concept of "Spaces" (world space, view space, projection spaces, local spaces and screen spaces) (c++, direct3d 11)

Tags: c++, direct3d11

So far, what i understand about these spaces is that they define a certain aspect of a games' 3d world. The view space is actually just the camera, and we define this by creating a matrix that contains the camera position, the camera target and the "up" direction of the camera.

This is all done in code as follows...

```
XMMATRIX CameraView;
XMVECTOR CameraPosition;                        
XMVECTOR CameraTarget;
XMVECTOR CameraUp;

/* Describing the matrix */
CameraPosition = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f);      
CameraTarget = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);         
CameraUp = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

/*  Creating the matrix*/
CameraView = XMMatrixLookAtLH(CameraPosition, CameraTarget, CameraUp);
```

I have a hard time trying to visualize this in my head. So in simple terms.. am i just "enabling" the player to move around at will by creating the `CameraView`? (assuming the 3d world is already created)

Can someone explain to me what exactly is happening here

Comment: To be code master, I think you should read books about graphic programming e.g http://opengles-book.com

Comment: I will read a bunch of textbooks once i transfer to a university, but before i do, I would like to do some projects on my own. I just need a simple explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suggestion: As you are completely new to DirectXMath and Direct3D, you should take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) and the [SimpleMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2013/01/08/simplemath-a-simplified-wrapper-for-directxmath.aspx) wrapper in particular. It will save you a lot of distraction here.

When you render an object, there's really only a single transformation in place. It takes the object from whatever coordinate system it is defined in (called 'local' or 'model' coordinate spaces) and the end result is a `x,y` pixel position and a `z` depth.

For humans, however, it's usually easier to think of this transformation as happening in stages--when in fact thanks to the power of homogenous coordinates and concatenation through multiplication, it's just one vector-matrix multiply in practice. This is often thought of as `world -> view -> projection`.

1. The 'world' matrix places the points defined in local coordinates to 'world' coordinates. This allows all the models to be in their own local coordinates, and then placed relative to one-another in a scene. The world coordinate system is also where you canonically define where your light sources are located. This is commonly created with a combination of `XMMatrixTranslation`, `XMMatrixRototation*`, and `XMMatrixScaling` functions multiplied together (and there are many other ways to create transformation matrices as well in the library including using quaternions for the rotations).
2. The 'view' matrix moves points in the world coordinate space into the view coordinate space, which is typically thought of as how the camera sees things. That's what the code snippet you show is computing. Given a camera position in world coordinates, and a camera target position in world coordinates, and an arbitrary 'up' vector, the function computes what the 'view' matrix needs to be using 'left-handed' viewing coordinates (hence the "LH").
3. The 'projection' matrix moves points from the view system into a generic normalized box that defines the 'projection' including applying either a perspective or orthogonal projection. For DirectXMath, this is done with `XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH`, `XMMatrixOrthographicLH`, related functions.

See [3D projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection)

**RE: Handedness**

The choice of 'left-handed' vs. 'right-handed' viewing systems is purely a matter of taste and how your content is defined. Historically Direct3D used left-handed coordinates, and OpenGL used right-handed coordinates. In modern programmable shaders, there's nothing built into the system that cares. You just have to be consistent. XNA Game Studio and SimpleMath use 'right-handed' systems. DirectXMath in 99% of cases uses either.

See [Right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule)

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation. I am really learning a lot here.

Answer (score 1):

Transforming objects into "view space" is basically repositioning them relative to the camera depending on the camera's position and orientation/rotation.

The view or camera matrix itself is made using the camera's reference frame: imagine an x, y and z vector coming out of the camera that follow any rotation of the camera so that they always come out of the camera's top, right and front. They are usually called the up, right and view vectors respectively.

The view vector is derived using the look at point and the position, i.e

view vector = lookAt - Position.

The camera's right vector is then created using the cross product of the newly calculated view vector and the up vector you supply.

right vector = view vector X up vector

Then finally the "real" up vector for the camera is created using the new view and right vectors

up vector = right vector X view Vector

As a very important note, you want to make sure the three vectors are ortho-normalized. That sounds very technical but just means that all three have the length of one and are truly at 90 degrees to each other, or funny stuff can happen to models like stretching and distortion.

How these vectors are used in the view matrix itself is to create the top left 3 x 3 portion of the matrix. Then, depending on whether you're using row or column vectors, the bottom most row or right most column uses the position of the camera.

Now, the real trick is the values stored are in fact the INVERSE of the position/rotation. Think about it. If you have a camera and move it right to position (2,0,0) you will have to translate all objects -2.0 to the left for the effect you'd expect for moving the camera. Likewise for rotations - rotate the camera right and objects should move left relative to the camera

So, for a camera positioned at (4,5,3) and not rotated, using column vectors in the view matrix should look like this:

```
[1 0 0 -4]
[0 1 0 -5]
[0 0 1 -3]
[0 0 0  1]
```

As Chuck Walbourn said, a lot of the time the transformation of many objects is one multiplication using a matrix produced from the world, view, projection matrices together but there are cases in which you would want to use the view space co ords from a model-view matrix (without the projection) in shaders like lighting depending on your approach.